# Unhandled Exception: Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I tried picking a picture from my gallery from an app I developed using Xamarin-forms, visual studio 2017. After selecting a picture, i keep getting that error. same as when using camera to take the picture.
I tried debugging it. But i was not able to get anything concrete from it.
It crashed when it got to var mediaFile

```
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App11.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Levels : ContentPage
    {
        public Levels ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private async void TakePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("camera", "not supported", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var mediaFile= await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });

        }

        private async void FromPhone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No pickphoto", "Not available", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (mediaFile == null)
                return;

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return mediaFile.GetStream();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take the following code about taking photos:

```
 private async void Takephoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Test",
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            CompressionQuality = 75,
            CustomPhotoSize = 50,
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
            MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });
    }
```

Here is the sample that you can take a look:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin